# Encoding instructions in C

Tags: c, encoding, instructions

Very new to this concept, and I've been referencing other instruction sets out there, but I've been trying to create a virtual machine where I actually encode the instructions.

This is what I've got:

```
enum OPCODE {
    MOV,
};

enum TARGET {
    A, B,
};

struct instr {
    unsigned char opcode;
    unsigned char target;
    uint64_t immediate;
};
```

Basically I have an instruction that has a 1 byte opcode, a 1 byte target, and a 8 byte immediate value. So for instance, a move instruction like: `MOV A, 50` that moves the value 50 into a will be 0, 0, 50 assuming that mov's opcode is 0, and the A register is 0.

How would I go around encoding this into a single value? The instruction adds up to an 80 bit/10 byte value which, as far as I know, is not a native type in C. What type would I use, and to store this could I use a union to squash it all into a single value?

... am I approaching this correctly at all?

Comment: Note also that you might need to add `__attribute__((packed))` to `struct instr` to ensure there is no padding between the members. And `uint64_t` is 8 bytes, not 4 bytes. On the other hand you might also want to align the members for performance.

Comment: @jotik Oops my bad on that, and good point about packing the structure :)

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by *"into a single value"*? An instance of `instr` would already be a single value. Why do you need this?

Comment: The `immediate` field takes up 64 bits, so you're never going to get anything smaller than `72` bits.

Comment: Encoding as an array of `uint8_t` is one option. On the x86 family of processors, there is an arbitrary limit of 14 bytes per instruction. You could adopt a similar restriction, which would allow you to use a fixed sized array to store any instruction.

Comment: Actually, the smallest will be 80 bits. 64 bits for `immediate`, 8 bits for `opcode`, and 8 bits for `target`. How do you think you could pack it better?

Comment: One might be interested in bit-fields.

Comment: You said **4 byte immediate value**. So why are you using `uint64_t` instead of `uint32_t`?

Comment: @Barmar Forgot to correct that part, I meant I 8 byte... I want a 64 bit integer as an immediate, not a 32 bit integer.

Comment: @jotik Now I'm not even sure what it means. I'm thinking in a way that I could print it to a file, but I guess I would do that byte by byte how user3386109 suggested?

Comment: @mosmo Yes, just take care of endianness for fields larger than 1 byte, then just `fwrite(&someInstruction, sizeof(struct instr), 1u, outFile)` for each instruction.

Comment: @jotik Ah I see, perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You would encode it into a single value of type `struct instr`:

```
struct instr a = { ... };
```

The variable `a` is a value that you can assign to other variables of type `struct instr`, pass (by value) when calling a function, use as a return value of the function call, etc. `struct instr` is a type that has values just like built-in types (`int`, `long`, etc).